# How to connect to a RPi with new-ly flashed SD?

Tags: sd-card, operating-systems

I flashed a fresh image onto SD. I do not have HDMI cable. RPi 3 is connected to router. Can I connect to it with out having a monitor? Does OS auto-install and how to get when it installed and started?

Comment: Which OS are you using? If you are using Raspbian (not noobs) you should be able to SSH to your Pi. You can find the IP address from your router or you can try raspberry.local as the hostname. Depending on the model of Pi you have you can also connect it to a tv via composite video.

Comment: Raspbian (no desctop, not noobs)

Comment: Which OS is your other computer (Windows, Mac or Linux)?

Comment: Windows (10 x64, I use Putty)

Comment: Which model Pi are youusing? How is connected to the network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1 :
    You must find the Pi's IP address in the local network.

```
sudo netdiscover -r [range IP for example 192.168.1.0]/24 -i enp0s25
```

Step 2 :
    Connect with SSH

```
ssh pi@[RPi_ipAddress]
```

Enter your password [for example: `"raspberry"`]

Comment: This assumes Linux or Mac, what happens if the OP only has a PC?

Comment: can use in windows putty [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)

Comment: But how would he find the IP as the command you gave does not work on a PC. You have made several assumptions in a rush to answer the question, that may not be valid. You should either make clear the limits of your answer or post a comment asking for clarification (I realise you do not have enough rep to do that yet), but you could have posted an answer asking for more info from the OP and it would eventually get flagged and one of the mods would convert it to a comment for you.

Comment: it is all true when you have Ethernet cable...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an Unix-like OS (e.g. MS Windows), you need to install needed commands or additional tools. I determine Raspberry IP addresses in subnet via

```
nmap -sn 10.42.43.1/24
```

Either install nmap under cygwin or natively and you should be done:
https://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html

Comment: There will be no flame wars about the *real* OS here. Windows by definition is an OS. Neither the objective flaws it might have nor your personal preferences need to be discussed here to answer the question.